# Add and fill a field in Python Toolbox (pyt) in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, fields-attributes, python-toolbox

I am using **python toolbox in ArcMap**, and I want to **add a new field** in a shapefile and after that I want to **fill this field** with the name of the shapefile.

I achieve to add a new field using **arcpy.AddField_management** function, but then I cannot fill this field. I am using arcpy.CalculateField_management function to fill it, however I think that this is a wrong way.

Any suggest is welcome.

The code is:

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "FIELD"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

# First parameter

    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Shape entrada",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="DEShapefile",
            parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

# Second parameter

param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Nuevo campo",
            name="field",
        datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    parameters = [param0, param1]
    return parameters

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    a= parameters[0].valueAsText
b= parameters[1].valueAsText


a=arcpy.AddField_management(a, b, "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

a=arcpy.CalculateField_management(a, b, "hola" ,"VB")

    return a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot calculate your field to contain the text `hola` is wrong string formatting in the expression parameter (look at the [Calculate Field GP tool docs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm)).

When using the `VB` parser, you need to supply a string inside double quotes. Look at the `'"hola"'`.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(
    in_table="U.S. Cities",
    field="CITY_NAME",
    expression='"hola"',
    expression_type="VB",
    code_block="")
```

You could alternatively use the `Python` parser. You would need to reverse the strings as in `"'hola'"`:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(
    in_table="U.S. Cities",
    field="CITY_NAME",
    expression="'hola'",
    expression_type="PYTHON_9.3",
    code_block="")
```

As you are writing a Python tool, it makes sense to use the `Python` expression instead of the `VB`.

Comment: It works. And can I specify the shapefile name instead of "hola"?

Comment: For sure. Look into the `arcpy.Describe` (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/03q30000001w000000/). You would need to use the `baseName` property.

Comment: And how have I use it in **arcpy.CalculateField_management** function? I write this: `desc = arcpy.Describe(parameters[0])` and then `a=arcpy.CalculateField_management(a, b, desc.baseName,"PYTHON_9.3",code_block="")`. But I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: I get this error: `ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: PRUEBAS 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PRUEBAS' is not defined
`.

Comment: Done. x) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273769/calculatefield-management-python-toolbox